# What is the difference between max_delay and muxdelay in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am generating some streams using ffmpeg (ffmpeg-20150409-git-df4fca2-win32-static). ffmpeg is used to transcode from MPEG2 video to HEVC. How are the parameters max_delay and muxdelay different? With both the parameters, I get the increase in the DTS-PCR difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`muxdelay` sets the delay in seconds while `max_delay` sets it in microseconds. The end result is the same. You can see the code that sets the underlying value in ffmpeg_opt.c

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c